# AWS Pyspark Glue job fails at glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

Working with a job in AWS Glue to perform an upsert from S3 to Redshift I ran into this error:

```
exception: java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "public.#table_stg" does not exist
```

Im using pre and post actions in my connection options so I can create a temp table as a staging phase. My code looks like this:

```
table_wo_schema = "my_table"
stg_table_name = f"#{table_wo_schema}_stg"
table_name = f"myschema.{table_wo_schema}"

pre_query = f"drop table if exists {stg_table_name};create table {stg_table_name} as select * from {table_name} where 1=2;"
post_query= f"delete from {table_name} using {stg_table_name} where {stg_table_name}.id = {table_name}.id ; insert into {table_name} select * from {stg_table_name}; drop table {stg_table_name};"

#Job fails here
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
    frame = dynamic_frame_to_write, 
    catalog_connection = "my-redshift-connection", 
    connection_options = {
        "preactions":pre_query,
        "dbtable": stg_table_name, 
        "database": "my-redshift-database",
        "postactions":post_query
        },
    redshift_tmp_dir = "s3://some/dir"
    )
```

I took the idea from here:

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sql-commands-redshift-glue-job/

what I've found is that, behind the scenes, the glueContext object adds the 'public' schema when none is provided in:

```
conection_options = { "dbtable" : "#my_table_stg" }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-jdbc

which will into a similar SQL statement chain:

```
--pre action statements
statement1;
statement2;
...
--write dynamic frame to Redshift
COPY public.#my_table_stg (column1, column2, ...) FROM 's3://some/path/manifest.json' CREDENTIALS '' FORMAT AS CSV NULL AS '@NULL@' manifest;
--post action statements
...
statement N;
```

As far as I know, temp tables may reside in a different schema dependending on the first element of the search_path. Despite this, it is not possible to reference a temp table preceded by any schema

```
--Invalid Redshift statement
select * from someschema.#temp_table

--Valid statement
select * from #temp_table
```

I don't know what configuration I'm missing to achieve the upsert job using temp tables.

To make it clear, I'm aware i could work around it by using normal tables instead of temporary ones, but I don't like the idea of having staging tables accesible from other sessions. I appreciate all kinds of help in advance

Comment: Did you get solution of this ?